# Path change ActiveXObject not working

Tags: java, path, activexobject

I am using `ActiveXObject` for some print jobs what I doing is placing `java` class file on **Desktop** and doing stuff as follows:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("cmd /c java HelloWorldPrinter1 \""+output+"\"");
```

It works fine.

I have moved my class file into `C:\printjob`

So I tried as follows:

```
 var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  shell.run("cmd /c C:/printjobjava/HelloWorldPrinter1 \""+output+"\"");
```

It is not working.

How can put path of a file correctly in `ActiveXObject`?
Have gone through various links but no use

Comment: please add `StackTrace` of Error to Identify the problem. There are so many Problem may found to your Code. It Depends
IS your `.class` File ` HelloWorldPrinter1.class ` present in C:/printjobjava` directory ??
 Thanks

Comment: @ Vikrant Kashyap it is purely depend upon ActivexObject nothing match with java

Comment: we cannot Identify which class file you are talking about because there is two .class file is here  first is your Program and second one is `HelloWorldPrinter1 `

Comment: my class file is inside `C:/printjob` directory

Comment: @ Vikrant Kashyap its dependency is ActivexObject not java class file. The class files works perfectly if i put on desktop. Read question carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer finally

`shell.run("cmd  /c java -cp C:\\printjob  HelloWorldPrinter1 \""+output+"\"");`